# How to guide the user to optional fields on the document?

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi

I create an envelope using the [Docusign eSign](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-csharp-client) client.  I have a radioGroup with 4 radio buttons.  These fields are optional and user is not required to make a choice.

When the document is presented for signing, DocuSign has an arrow to the left of the document that guides the user from one field to another.  However, it completely skips my optional radio group which means that the user won't ever even read it.

How can I tell DocuSign to include my optional fields in its guide?

P.S. This functionality seems to be present for the UI product as indicated by [documentation](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-optional-fields), but I don't see how to enable it via the API.

Comment: How do you do this from the UI? I don't see any indication of this in the link you provided, can you explain?

Comment: @InbarGazit See documentation link.  https://i.imgur.com/1AECfdr.png

Comment: This is required/optional fields, nothing to do with "guiding the user". You can do that from the API just fine.

Comment: @InbarGazit It does, because in that example if the field is not required, the guide will still go to that field, but the field itself will be in a different color to denote that the user does have "have" to fill it out.

Comment: The web app uses the API, you can see what it does and do the same. To do that use API Logging and you'll see the API calls being made and you can do the same.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJYTDcc7cZw

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are misunderstanding the documentation. The guide is for how to make a tab optional/required. The arrow on the left of the page will guide you over all fields while clicking on it. However, if the recipient decide to skip optional field will not force them to go back

**UPDATE**
You can control Navigation through, Settings > Signing Settings > Auto Navigation > Navigate all fields